# One million positive integers

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

How many different (multi)sets of one million positive integers are such that their sum equals their product?

Comment: The sequence of the number of solutions for n = 1, 2, 3, ... does not appear to be in the OEIS. https://www.jstor.org/stable/3621488

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial (?) answer

> It seems reasonable to use as smaller numbers as possible, otherwise product will easily exceed the sum. So if we try to maximize the number of $1$'s used:
>  Consider the multiset of $1000000$ integers: $\{1, 1, 1, \dots, 2, 1000000 \}$
>  The sum and product are both equal to $2000000$.

> This construction works for any size $n$ of the multiset: use $2$ and $n$ once and fill the remaining values with $1$s. I doubt if there are any more multisets that work but I don't have a proof.

Answer (score 2):

Another partial solution
Only using two values >1 there are already a lot of such multisets

> then ab = a+b+999998
>  thus (a-1)(b-1) = 999999 = 3x3x3x7x11x13x37
>  thus a=2,4,8,10,12,14,20,26,32,36,38.. all work
>
>  note that these are not the only ones, e.g. 4x4x66667 (padded with ones) works too.

Answer (score 1):

About the equation $a_1 \cdots a_k = a_1 + \cdots + a_k$ for integers $a_i$, it's not hard to show that

> $a_1 \cdots a_k \leq 2k$.
>
>  For a proof, see e.g. [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h478195p2677576).

The rough idea is then

> to check all multisets $\{a_1, \dots, a_k\}$ such that each $a_i$ is at least $2$ and their product doesn't exceed $2e6$. This is doable with the help of a computer.
>
>  There are various algorithmic improvements which I don't expand here.